# ListView showing only the last item in the first position of ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I want to show some items in a list view. The problem is that the list view only shows the last item in the first position of the list view. It shows the the no. of items correctly but the remaining positions remain blank.

Can't understand where I am doing wrong. Any help please? I am attaching a screenshot here[image: Screenshot]

`MainActivit.java`

```java
ListView topicList;
ArrayList<Topics> topics;
ArrayList<Topics> topicsArrayList;
TopicAdapter topicAdapter;

//Inside onCreat method  
topicList = findViewById(R.id.lv_list);

        //Array list to show items in the list view
        topics = new ArrayList<>();
        topicAdapter = new TopicAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_row, topics);
        topicList.setAdapter(topicAdapter);

        //Array list to add the list items
        topicsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        Topics vumika = new Topics();
        vumika.setTopicName("Vumika");
        topicsArrayList.add(vumika);

        Topics prachin_yug = new Topics();
        vumika.setTopicName("Prachin Yug");
        topicsArrayList.add(prachin_yug);

        Topics madhya_yug = new Topics();
        vumika.setTopicName("Madhya Yug");
        topicsArrayList.add(madhya_yug);

        Topics adhunik_yug = new Topics();
        vumika.setTopicName("Adhunik Yug");
        topicsArrayList.add(adhunik_yug);

        //Add all the topics to the topic list
        if (topicsArrayList != null || topicsArrayList.size() > 0) {
            topics.addAll(topicsArrayList);
            topicAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

`TopicAdapter.java` class

```java
public class TopicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<Topics> topics;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public TopicAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Topics> topics) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.topics = topics;
    }

    public TopicAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Topics> topics, ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.topics = topics;
        this.viewHolder = viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return topics.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return topics.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (inflater != null) {
                row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
                viewHolder.topicName = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_topic_name);
                row.setTag(viewHolder);

            }
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Topics topic = topics.get(position);
        viewHolder.topicName.setText(topic.getTopicName());

        return row;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView topicName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Zoe, I will remember your advice for my future posts

Answer (score 4):

It shows the last item because you are repeatedly using the `vumika.setTopicName()` setter method. you have to set the name to each every new Topics object.

The correct one is

```
Topics vumika = new Topics();
vumika.setTopicName("Vumika");
topicsArrayList.add(vumika);

Topics prachin_yug = new Topics();
prachin_yug.setTopicName("Prachin Yug");
topicsArrayList.add(prachin_yug);

Topics madhya_yug = new Topics();
madhya_yug.setTopicName("Madhya Yug");
topicsArrayList.add(madhya_yug);

Topics adhunik_yug = new Topics();
adhunik_yug.setTopicName("Adhunik Yug");
topicsArrayList.add(adhunik_yug);
```

Comment: OMG, That's the right thing, I didn't notice that, it's a copy-paste mistake, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

The first topic `Topics vumika = new Topics();` is added every time to the `topicsArrayList`, **by changing its name**. So the last name is reflected. So, use the following :-

`vumika.setTopicName("Adhunik Yug");` is the last name which is written to `vumika`

```
  Topics vumika = new Topics();
  vumika.setTopicName("Vumika");
  topicsArrayList.add(vumika);

  Topics prachin_yug = new Topics();
  prachin_yug.setTopicName("Prachin Yug");
  topicsArrayList.add(prachin_yug);

  Topics madhya_yug = new Topics();
  madhya_yug.setTopicName("Madhya Yug");
  topicsArrayList.add(madhya_yug);

  Topics adhunik_yug = new Topics();
  adhunik_yug.setTopicName("Adhunik Yug");
  topicsArrayList.add(adhunik_yug);
```

Comment: Thank you, its a copy-paste mistake, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 3):

There is copy paste mistake, only `vumika` is changing, Change like following

```
 topics = new ArrayList<>();
        topicAdapter = new TopicAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_row, topics);
        topicList.setAdapter(topicAdapter);

        //Array list to add the list items
        topicsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        Topics vumika = new Topics();
        vumika.setTopicName("Vumika");
        topicsArrayList.add(vumika);

        Topics prachin_yug = new Topics();
        prachin_yug.setTopicName("Prachin Yug");
        topicsArrayList.add(prachin_yug);

        Topics madhya_yug = new Topics();
        madhya_yug.setTopicName("Madhya Yug");
        topicsArrayList.add(madhya_yug);

        Topics adhunik_yug = new Topics();
        adhunik_yug.setTopicName("Adhunik Yug");
        topicsArrayList.add(adhunik_yug);
```